# Do I need a search engine for a model with 20+ attributes

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, performance, postgresql, search-engine

I am planning to develop an application which will have a Model with lots of attributes on it. These attributes will be one of the most important parts of the application thus users will be firing search queries most of the time in order to find the result they are looking for.

My question is, is it OK to relay on mysql or postgres for it, or should i start with something like solr, elasticsearch from the beginning.

I want this application **not to consume lots of memory while doing these searches**. This is the first thing I want, since i will start with a basic server setup with 2 cores and 4gb ram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of them (rdbms and fulltext se) are valid technologies...mainly it depends on

- your access pattern
- features you want to offer in your search services

For instance if you want to do fulltext search, or you want things like autocompletion, faceting,stemming Solr or ES is your friend. On the other side, if you want to pickup data in realtime (and you don't want things above) I would use an rdbms

In general: you described a bit your "non" functional requirements, but the decision involves functional requirements, too. Definitely

Comment: My app will need both real time, autocompletion features. I guess I will need a search engine at some point. I was also wondering, since there wont be so many complicated model associations in the app, would I still need a search engine do you think?

Comment: If you need such features (and others that a search engine offers) i think you should use that. Depending on your context you could search within a search engine and then gather rwal timw data from a database...but that actually depends on your context.

Comment: If you need such features (and others that a search engine offers) i think you should use that. Depending on your context you could search within a search engine and then gather rwal timw data from a database...but that actually depends on your context. About Solr vs ES, sorry I don't know ES so I'm not the right person for giving you some suggestion here